# netezza - formatting timestamp to 1/100s / 1/10s of seconds

Tags: sql, netezza

I could do the formatting of a timestamp to seconds as follows.

`to_char('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') --> 2017-02-20 08:22:44`

I need to format the above time stamp into 100s and 10s of seconds.

--> `2017-02-20 08:22:44.17` (formatted to 1/100s of second)

--> `2017-02-20 08:22:44.2` (formatted to 1/10 th of second)

I tried the postgres way of doing as below, but this gives error in the Netezza platform I'm working with

```
select '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(2), '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(1);

ERROR [42000] ERROR:  'select '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(2), '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(1) LIMIT 1000'
error                                               ^ found "(" (at char 44) expecting a keyword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it does work on PostgreSQL and I believe it will work on Netezza.  (Unfortunately I don't have access to a Netezza box any more so I'm just relying on the documentation):

```
select 
     '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp,
     to_char('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.') || 
         round(to_char('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp, 'MS')::float / 10) as hundredths,
     to_char('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.') || 
         round(to_char('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp, 'MS')::float / 100) as tenths;

        timestamp        |       hundredths       |        tenths         
-------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------
 2017-02-20 08:22:44.166 | 2017-02-20 08:22:44.17 | 2017-02-20 08:22:44.2
(1 row)
```

Comment: this works !! - just curious on what's the UI interface / app you have used to run the query and get the results ?

Comment: I'm glad that works on Netezza too.  The UI I use, almost always, is the command line (psql for PostgreSQL, nzsql for Netezza, sqlplus for Oracle, etc.).  I find the command line gives me a closer interface to the database and helps me produce repeatable code.  I can keep each script in a file and run it again and again, rather than trying to remember which boxes I ticked last time.  The Pragmatic Programmer by Hunt & Thomas, section 15 "Shell Games" explains it very well.  You might also look at my website http://thedatastudio.net.